# How to convert rmvb to mp4 with same quality by using ffmpeg?

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, converters

I found a batch file that can convert rmvb to mp4 using ffmpeg command, but the filesize become very big after converted(700mb become 3gb), so can I change something in the script below to make the filesize smaller and same quality?

> FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.rmvb') DO ffmpeg -i "%%G" -vcodec
> mpeg4 -qscale:v 2 -acodec aac "%%~nG.mp4"

And also why Im keep getting this message? Is it something wrong with the script?
[image]

Comment: try setting a higher qscale, that should significantly reduce the file size, at the cost of shittier video quality. try `qscale:v 17`, should be pretty good quality still, see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#FAQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify the *for* loop to:

```
for %%G in (*.rmvb) do ffmpeg -i "%%~G" -c:v h264 -c:a aac "%%~nG.mp4"
```

This converts to *h264* video and *aac* audio. These codecs quite common at present.

Video defaults to *CRF 23* while audio should default to *128k*.

This should give reasonable quality at perhaps a tenth of the bitrate shown in your image of *9300k* down to perhaps under *1000k*.

The duration errors happen sometimes and may seem a lot though the end video may still appear as good as the original.